# Hiding and unhiding columns toggle button

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a simple toggle button which continues to hide the next column from column 5 onwards every time it is clicked.

e.g.

1. click button to hide column 6/F
2. click button again to hide column 7/G
3. click button again to hide column 8/H
4. etc

And i want to create a button which does the reverse as well.

e.g.

1. click button to unhide column 6/F
2. click button again to unhide 7/G
3. etc

I have the below code, what do I need to add so it continues to show/hide the next column every time I click/run the function?

```
function hideCol()
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('testsheet'); //put the name of the sheet in place of 'Main'
  
  sheet.hideColumns(6); //F

}

function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Hide Columns', 'hideCol')
      .addItem("Show Columns", 'show')
      .addToUi();
}

function show() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('testsheet'); //put the name of the sheet in place of 'Main'
  sheet.showColumns(6);  //F

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

- The logic would be to iterate the number of columns starting from column `5` onwards. To do this, you can create an array for which the first element is `5` up to the last available column, provided by [getMaxColumns](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getmaxcolumns):

  ```
  var array =  Array(sheet.getMaxColumns()-4).fill().map((element, index) => index + 5);
  ```
- If you click on the `Hide Columns` button and you encounter an **unhidden** column then you simply **hide** it.
- If you click on the `Show Columns` button and you encounter a **unhidden** column then you **unhide** the previous one.
- To check whether a particular column is hidden or not, you need to use [isColumnHiddenByUser](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#iscolumnhiddenbyusercolumnposition).

### Solution:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Hide Columns', 'hideCol')
      .addItem("Show Columns", 'show')
      .addToUi();
}

function hideCol() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('testsheet'); //put the name of the sheet in place of 'Main'
  const array =  Array(sheet.getMaxColumns()-4).fill().map((element, index) => index + 5);
  for(let col of array){
     if(!sheet.isColumnHiddenByUser(col)){
         sheet.hideColumns(col);
         break;
     }
  }
}

function show() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('testsheet'); //put the name of the sheet in place of 'Main'
  const array =  Array(sheet.getMaxColumns()-4).fill().map((element, index) => index + 5);
  for(let col of array){
     if(sheet.isColumnHiddenByUser(col)){
         sheet.showColumns(col);
         break;
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! The **hide function** works perfectly. In the **show function**, I would prefer if the columns started unhiding from the first column e.g if columns 6-10 are hidden, it would unhide column 6 first, then 7, etc. At the moment it works backwards e.g. column 10 unhides first, then 9, etc. I tried changing the numbers in the function but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: @NoobCoder I thank you for your feedback, please check my updated answer and if it worked for you confirm the answer. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I actually tried removing the 1 before posting my question and it didn't work, dunno why it worked when you did it! That's perfect and all works fine. Appreciate that!

Comment: @NoobCoder I also removed the `!` from the if condition. Glad it worked out !